# Kill a process which has same GID for another process

Tags: c++, unix, process

Want to kill a process of a tree.
 For example: A->B->C->D->E
I want to kill process C,D,E but not A and B.

Suppose the Parent id of all process is 1234.

```
ps x -o  "%p %r %y %x %c 
{PID_A} 1234
{PID_B} 1234
{PID_C} 1234
{PID_D} 1234
{PID_E} 1234
```

I cannot do kill -9 -1234 since its killing A and B as well.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do `kill -9` except as a last resort after politer mechanisms such as `kill -1` or `kill -15` (aka `kill -HUP` or `kill -TERM`) have failed.

Your question starts with `A->B->C->D->E` which suggests that A launches B, and B launches C, and C launches D, and D launches E.  However, then you say that 1234 is the parent PID of all of B, C, D, E, and probably A too (assuming that A is not PID = 1234).  So, in the second scenario, you have 6 processes: 1234, and A through E, each of which was started by 1234.

In some ways, it doesn't matter much.  The only way to kill processes C, D, E without also killing A and B (and 1234) is by listing the process IDs of C, D, E.  Unless something has taken steps to place the three processes into the same process group or session as each other, and in a separate process group or session from A, B (and 1234), there aren't any alternatives.

You can look at the specification of the [`kill()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) system call:

> If *pid* is greater than 0, *sig* shall be sent to the process whose process ID is equal to *pid*.
>
> If *pid* is 0, *sig* shall be sent to all processes (excluding an unspecified set of system processes) whose process group ID is equal to the process group ID of the sender, and for which the process has permission to send a signal.
>
> If *pid* is -1, *sig* shall be sent to all processes (excluding an unspecified set of system processes) for which the process has permission to send that signal.
>
> If *pid* is negative, but not -1, *sig* shall be sent to all processes (excluding an unspecified set of system processes) whose process group ID is equal to the absolute value of *pid*, and for which the process has permission to send a signal.

Those are the signalling options available.  None of those options applies usefully to either organization of processes 1234 and A … E (killing C, D, E and leaving 1234, A, B unkilled).

Comment: Its just an example but in real i am not aware of how many children or gran children C has.

So is there any way to kill all the children including C with its C's process id rather than the GID.

kill -9 PID_of_C is not working for me ...

Comment: You can kill C and all its descendents only if C made itself a process group leader and its children didn't make themselves process group leaders.  Then you can signal the process group.  If the processes ignore or catch the signal and do not exit, then they won't die.  You can't catch or ignore SIGKILL, of course, so it is the last resort — but it used to be the case that processes using NFS (network file system) files could get blocked if the network connection failed, and there was no way to kill the process even with SIGKILL.  A reboot, or fixing the network, was the only way to fix them.

Comment: i got a way to kill the children under C and also C through setpgid().

i am assigning the c's process id to its group id of c and all its children and it works fine for C++.

But i want to do it through a script rather than a c++ code .
is there any similar function for shell scripting like setpgid() in c++?

Comment: There isn't.  I've not investigated precisely what Bash does, but it certainly tends to manipulate process groups and sessions and so on.  It would be feasible to write a 'cantrip' program, similar in style to `su` or `nohup`, that puts itself into a new process group and then runs whatever command is given as arguments. This is simple C (or C++, but I'd definitely use C for the job) code.  You could call the program `setpgid`, even.